# Details of a request not shown in App Engine dashboard

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to debug my app engine application, but when I view the Logs on appengine.google.com, none of the logging information is available.

Quite simply, I have calls to logging.info, logging.error in my code that I know are being hit... but when I try to "expand" a request in the appengine.google.com dashboard, there are no details about the request.

It seems if I wait long enough sometimes the logging information "appears", but this can take a few hours.

Am I missing something here? I can provide a screenshot if my explanation is unclear.

Comment: Please clarify. You change your minimum log severity to info, you see the request, but when you expand the request, none of your logged statements appear? You can expand the exact same request hours later and the log messages show up?

Comment: Exactly. It is like the logs are processed in a queue that has been throttled.

Comment: Weird. I've never run into a delay. Are you emitting a high volume of log messages?

Comment: Nope, this is on a testing application, 0.033 QPS.